# Problem with import a External List

Tags: development, error, error-handling

Why i import a External list, and Add to my code the error is Shown:

> Name cannot begin with the '-' character, hexadecimal value 0x2D. Line
>   1, position 316.

Here is screen Shot. How can I run the code without this error. Where is main reason.

[image]

Comment: Are you having `for ( int iterator - 0` rather than `for ( int iterator = 0` at the start of the loop? The quality of the image is ridiculously poor so makes it practically impossible to read the text.

Comment: @TZHX Try zooming in...

Comment: Try analyzing by debugging what the query "listaDniUrlopow" actually found...

Comment: Thanks :) I deboug and found aut a problem Its was because the first elements start with "<--"